# pandas DataFrame add a new column and fillna

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column to a pandas dataframe, like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['one'] = pd.Series({'1':4, '2':6})
print (df)
df['two'] = pd.Series({'0':4, '2':6})
print (df)
```

This yields:

```
   one  two
1    4  NaN
2    6    6
```

However, I would the result to be,

```
   one  two
0   NaN  4
1    4  NaN
2    6    6
```

How do you do that?

Comment: If I may suggest a more concise title, such as "Adding a new column with reindexing / new index / non-overlapping index" - as there's nothing about fillna in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join`, telling pandas exactly how you want to do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['one'] = pd.Series({'1':4, '2':6})
df.join(pd.Series({'0':4, '2':6}, name = 'two'), how = 'outer')
```

This results in

```
   one  two
0  NaN    4
1    4  NaN
2    6    6
```

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use `pd.concat`:

```
ser1 = pd.Series({'1':4, '2':6})
ser2 = pd.Series({'0':4, '2':6})
df = pd.concat((ser1, ser2), axis=1)
```

to get

```
    0   1
0 NaN   4
1   4 NaN
2   6   6
```